# erlang processes communication (code error)

Tags: process, erlang, spawn

I am new to Erlang. In my code I try to give each of my 2 processes a list of numbers. The process `oid` should send all even numbers in its list to the process `eid`, which should send all odd numbers in its process to `oid`. When a process finishes filtering its own list it starts reading the messages received from the other process, adds them to the output list, and finally prints that list.

When I run the code I get these errors:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 28-Apr-2015::23:01:25 ===
>   Error in process <0.296.0> with exit value: {if_clause,[{test,odd,2,[{file,"test.erl"},{line,25}]}]}
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 28-Apr-2015::23:01:25 ===
>   Error in process <0.297.0> with exit value: {if_clause,[{test,even,2,[{file,"test.erl"},{line,49}]}]}

Here's my code:

```
-module(test).
-export([start/0]).
-export([odd/2]).
-export([even/2]).

start() -> 
    register(oid, spawn(test, odd, [[1,2,3,4,5],[]])),
    register(eid, spawn(test, even, [[6,7,8,9],[]])).
%---------------------------------------------
odd(c,O) ->
    receive
        done -> 
            lists:foreach(
                fun(X) -> io:fwrite("~p\n", X) end, 
                io:fwrite("~p\n", oid)
            );
        Num -> 
            O++[Num],
            odd(c,O)
    end;
odd([],O) ->
    eid ! done,
    odd(c,O);

odd([A|Rest],O) -> 
    if 
        A rem 2 =:= 0 ->
            eid ! A;
        A rem 2 =/= 0 ->
            O++[A],
            odd([Rest],O)
    end.
%--------------------------------------------
even(c,E)->
    receive
        done -> 
            lists:foreach(
                fun(X) -> io:fwrite("~p\n", X) end, 
                io:fwrite("~p\n", eid)
            );
        Num ->
            E++[Num],
            even(c,E)
    end;

even([],E) ->
    oid ! done,
    even(c,E);

even([A|Rest],E) -> 
    if 
        A rem 2 =/= 0 ->
            oid ! A;
        A rem 2 =:= 0 ->
            E++[A],
            even([Rest],E)
    end.
%---------------------------------------------
pri([H|T]) ->
    io:format("~p~n", [H]),
    pri(T);
pri([]) ->
    true.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this code. Did you compile it?

First, an easy problem: your `io:fwrite/2` calls need to have their arguments to be printed passed in a list, not as individual terms, so this:

```
io:fwrite("~p\n", oid)
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
io:fwrite("~p\n", [oid])
```

But there's little point in printing a constant `oid` like that anyway. You should just get rid of this code:

```
lists:foreach(
    fun(X) -> io:fwrite("~p\n", X) end, 
    io:fwrite("~p\n", oid)
);
```

(which is broken and won't compile anyway) and use your `pri/1` function instead (or `pri/2`, as shown later).

Next, you're attempting to add elements to lists as if the lists were mutable. Variables in Erlang are immutable. Instead of this:

```
O++[A],
odd([Rest],O)
```

you need:

```
odd(c,O++[Num])
```

to create a new list to pass to the next iteration, or better yet:

```
odd(c,[Num|O])
```

which is more efficient than appending because it simply adds a new head to the list. Note though that this builds the list backwards, so we'll need to reverse it later. Fortunately, reversing a list is very inexpensive.

Next, your `if` statement error messages are caused by the way you pass `Rest` recursively. When you have the construct `[A|Rest]`, the `Rest` variable *is already a list*. There's no need to pass it as `[Rest]`; it should just be passed as `Rest`. Let's say `A` is `1` and `Rest` is the list `[2,3,4,5]`; when you pass it to the next recursive call as `[Rest]`, the `[A|Rest]` in the new call is equivalent to `[[2,3,4,5] | []]` and the error occurs because `[2,3,4,5] rem 2` is a meaningless operation.

Another problem with the `odd/2` and `even/2` functions is that they use `if` at all, since they can use function clauses instead. The `if` is not often used in idiomatic Erlang code. Still another problem with those functions is that the clauses that send messages don't make recursive calls to handle any elements remaining in `Rest`. So instead of this:

```
odd([A|Rest],O) -> 
    if 
        A rem 2 =:= 0 ->
            eid ! A;
        A rem 2 =/= 0 ->
            O++[A],
            odd([Rest],O)
    end.
```

you could instead write this:

```
odd([A|Rest],O) when A rem 2 =:= 0 ->
    eid ! A,
    odd(Rest,O);
odd([A|Rest],O) ->
    odd(Rest,[A|O]).
```

Note that this avoids the need for two `rem` tests, since any number not detected by the guard in the first clause as being even is automatically odd and so is handled by the second clause. Note also that instead of `O++[A]` we're using the prepending form `[A|O]` to construct the new list.

One more problem is your artificial way of handling the end of the list by passing the atom `c` to `odd/2` and `even/2`. A better approach is to make `odd/1` and `even/1` and leave the `c` out altogether:

```
odd(O) ->
    receive
        done ->
            L = lists:sort(lists:reverse(O)),
            pri(oid,L);
        Num ->
            odd([Num|O])
    end.
```

This approach uses `pri/2` to do the printing, and the list passed to it is reversed here to undo the effects of building it via prepending, and sorted to put it in order. The `pri/2` function looks like this:

```
pri(Id, [H|T]) ->
    io:format("~p: ~p~n", [Id, H]),
    pri(Id,T);
pri(_, []) ->
    true.
```

If you run the whole thing, you get something like this:

```
2> test:start().
eid: 2
oid: 1
eid: 4
oid: 3
true
oid: 5
eid: 6
oid: 7
eid: 8
oid: 9
```

where the `true` in the middle is the result of the `test:start()` call, and the order of the printing from the two processes is indeterminate since they're concurrent.

Comment: Great post. Is there any point to reversing the list only to sort it?

Comment: Even though sort by itself solves the problem, I left the reverse and sort as two discrete steps because I wanted the reverse to be very visible. This is because the post explains how when building lists using `[Head|Tail]` it's common to end up with a list that's in reverse order from what you really want, and so reversing it at the end is common. I kept the reverse call there to remind the reader of that.

Comment: That is totally Super.
I have another question, how can I make the processes do their work and receive messages as they arrive. I have seen some loop() implementations, but they all suggest that the process is busy waiting. Is there a way to implement notifications ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Another thing that I did is to add
getit(ID,Acc)->
receive
 done-> 
        pri(ID,Acc);
 Num->
 getit(ID,[Num|Acc])
end.
instead of odd/1 and even/1 since they they do the same thing

Comment: Yes, that's a good change. You could in fact collapse all of `even` and `odd` to one function if you process the incoming list with `lists:filter` and just pass a different predicate to the function to test for even and odd numbers. But to address your earlier question about receiving messages as they arrive, look into using an `after 0` clause in a `receive`; this lets you check the queue for messages and handle them if present but not block if there are no messages.